# Should we remove recommendation tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Today, I realized that a "recommendation" tag exists. As the tag itself suggests "opinion-based question", should we discourage its use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Different communities in SE take different stances on this matter. Recommendations aren't neccessarily a bad thing: see the successful site [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Personally, I do think well asked recommendation questions can be fine, e.g.: *What product works well for cleaning [specific thing]?*.

Given we certainly don't have a problem with too many recommendation questions, I would just...not bother about this just now. If there are specific questions you think are a bad fit then by all means highlight them but making general decisions like this is too much rule-lawyering for where we are now.

Comment: I agree. According to area51, our main difficulty is to make people join the site. It is better not to bug people. Given that, the answer must be crafted correctly and not to be opinion-based. Maybe we can keep an eye on that.

Comment: As of today, we have a measly three questions with that tag, so if we wanted to remove it, the effort would be minimal. OTOH, users can still ask super opinion-based questions without a specific tag. They usually start with “What is the best...” So I agree - leave it as it is (for now), keep checking new questions as usual and reconsider this topic when (or if) it becomes a problem.